# Change order of keyboard layouts

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

On Windows 7 we had the option of changing the order of keyboard layouts, so I could have my preferred layout as first to have it be the default at startup.

On Windows 10 I can’t find that option anymore. How can that be achieved in Windows 10?

Comment: Control panel -> Language. Pay your attention to _Advanced settings_ as well (I hope `Win-10` behaviour could be similar to `Win-8`)

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks. But Windows 10 is different. - No way to change it from there.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and @JosefZ's approach worked. You can still access the Control Panel's language options, it exists in duplicate with the new Settings app.

Answer (score 6):

- Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Change Input Methods > Options (for the given language)
- Remove all layouts but the one you prefer at the top
- Save
- Go back into Options, and add the layouts back in the order you prefer

Very clunky, but it's the only way I've found to set it.

Comment: This is the correct answer still. Just reorganize the keyboards by adding and removing until the stack is ordered.

Comment: Jesus Christ, is Microsoft even reading this or just avoiding questions like this all the time??

Comment: There's no "Clock, Language, and Region\Language" for me, only "Clock and Region". I'm on 1803.

Comment: I did this on Windows 11. Now I have 2 Spanish keyboards. I'm going back to Linux

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, write "control" and press Enter.
It will open Control Panel.

Go to "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language".

In "Change your language preferences" page select any language and use "Move up" or "Move down" buttons above.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There's no "Clock, Language, and Region\Language" for me, only "Clock and Region". I'm on 1803.

Comment: I have English, Danish and Russian. English and Danish share an input method, but two different keyboards. It is only possible to drag between English and Russian input methods, so I always have Danish in between. Danish can only be last if Russian is the default input method. This doesn't work very well with my work flow.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange them in Language settings: (Settings -> Time & Language -> Language)

[image: Preferred languages]

Comment: How to add a good inline image that improves the question.  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.